# How do I compute the determinant of a transfer function matrix without having to use "syms"?

Tags: matlab, determinants, nyquist

I intend to compute the determinant of a transfer matrix and then subject to a nyquist analysis by making the nyquist plot but the problem is that the determinant command doesn't recognizes the transfer matrix. The code is shown below

```
clc
clear all;
close all;

g11 = tf(12.8,[16.7 1],'InputDelay',1)
g12 = tf(-18.9,[21 1],'InputDelay',3)
g21 = tf(6.6,[10.9 1],'InputDelay',7)
g22 = tf(-19.4,[14.4 1],'InputDelay',3)

G=[g11 g12 ; g21 g22]

[re,im,w] = nyquist(G)

F=2.55;


s=tf('s');
%syms s;

ggc11 = g11*(0.96*(1+3.25*F*s)/(3.25*F^2*s))
ggc12 = g12*(0.534*(1+3.31*F*s)/(3.31*F^2*s))
ggc21 = g21*(0.96*(1+3.25*F*s)/(3.25*F^2*s))
ggc22 = g22*(0.534*(1+3.31*F*s)/(3.31*F^2*s))

GGc=[ggc11 ggc12 ; ggc21 ggc22];

L=eye(2)+ GGc;

W= -1 + det(L)

nyquist(W)
```

The error that appears is as follows

Undefined function 'det' for input arguments of type 'ss'.

Error in BLT_code (line 30)
W= -1 + det(L)

I would like to avoid the 'syms' command as I would not be able to do the nyquist plot then. Is there any alternative way of computing the nyquist plot of the same ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to calculate the determinant of a transfer function and use this to plot a nyquist diagram?

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty sure about that. Right now I know a way of doing it and that is by partitioning L into sub-matrices and then doing it manually. I needed to know if there is any other alternative.

Comment: The intention is to plot the closed loop log modulus of W and then determine the biggest log modulus from the plot.

Answer (score 0):

I am stuck in the same boat, trying to calculate the determinant of transfer function matrices for the purpose of checking the MIMO Nyquist stability criteria, see [MIMO Stability ETH Zurich](https://people.ee.ethz.ch/~ifa_cs2/Notes_MIMO_Nyquist.pdf) [Lecture slides (pg 10)](https://people.ee.ethz.ch/~ifa_cs2/CS2_lecture08.small.pdf). Unfortunately there does not seem to be a simple MATLAB command for this. I figured it can be evaluated manually.

If you have a TF matrix G(s) of the following form:

```
G = [g_11 g_12; g_21 g_22];
```

you can obtain the determinant by evaluating it as per its original definition as

```
det_G = g_11*g_22 - g_12*g_21;
```

This will result in a 1x1 TF variable. Of course, this method gets much too complicated for anything  above a 2x2 system.